# delay on opening start menu on windows 10 and also keyboard not working for search

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

i installed windows 10 couple of day ago (upgrade from 8.1) , from first day i had a problem that was , after working with pc about 2-3 hour when click on start button , the menu opened with 1 second delay and also search in start menu not working (typing with keyboard not working in start menu)

i do some search in internet and find this solution

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

this work , but it is temporary and will work just for 2 or 3 hour and the same problem after this time

also i added prompt in loop in above code to find which app cause this problem , but after finishing the job , start menu problem was not fixed (because of number of app i cant to this again )

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you're looking for an answer to the cause of the slowdown of the button in Windows itself, but I can tell you when I had a similiar problem back in Windows 8 on my work computer (the Windows search tool worked for me but it was painfully slow), I started using Launchy (http://www.launchy.net/) which is a 3rd party launcher for Windows. In addition to being more reliable and faster, it also supports plugins and is pretty customizable.